# Order By Date Difference Between Two Date Columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has two datetime columns (one for start time and one for end time).

I need to be able to select all entries and order them based on the time difference between these two columns (the period between the start and end time columns)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this::

```
select * from table order by TIMEDIFF(to, from)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(endDate, starDate);
```

[edit]
The above query works with *dates*. As pointed out by Sashi Kant, it would ignore the *time* part of your `DATETIME`

On the other hand, [`TIMEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) fails if the difference is outside of the [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html) range (`-838:59:59` to `838:59:59`).

A complete solution could be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY
    DATEDIFF(endDate, starDate),
    TIMEDIFF(TIME(endDate), TIME(starDate));
```

Probably performs terribly, though... If such precision is required, and if the difference between the two dates may be outside of the `TIME` range, then splitting each of your `DATETIME` columns into two `DATE` and `TIME` columns would certainly perform better, assuming you would apply one index on each of the four resulting columns.

Comment: it only shows the date difference, what about the entries having to and from in the same day

Comment: @SashiKant Correct, TIMEDIFF() is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT something FROM table ORDER BY TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are `mysql` defined functions to compute the difference between two `timestamp`s, like `TIME_TO_SEC` and `TIMEDIFF`.

`SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(from_time, to_time)) diff from your_table order by diff;`

Answer (score 0):

This is correct: select * from table order by TIMEDIFF(to, from)

But if you are not selecting timediff in select statement you might have to add this line of code:

SET sql_mode = '';

select * from table order by TIMEDIFF(to, from)

to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who just needs the time distance between two timestamps, irrespective or without having to know which date is earlier and which date is later, you could use the following:

```
SELECT t.*,
TIMEDIFF( t.date_column, t.other_date_column ) AS distance
FROM table t
ORDER BY IF(distance<0, 0-distance, distance)
```

Or if you have a fixed/static target timestamp:

```
SELECT t.*,
TIMEDIFF( t.date_column, '2021-04-20' ) AS distance
FROM table t
ORDER BY IF(distance<0, 0-distance, distance)
```

The `IF()` function always returns a positive "distance" measurement of time between the two timestamps. This allowed me to find the nearest available record whether it was earlier or later than the target timestamp.